# Kernel 4.8.7 failure on cpufreq - CentOS 7

Tags: kernel, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, kernel-panic, kernel-parameters

After upgrading my CentOS 7 kernel from 3.10.0 to 4.8.7, while rebooting the system I will get the following lines:

```
[    0.641455] cpufreq: cpufreq_online: Failed to initialize policy for cpu: 0 (-19)

[    0.641734] cpufreq: cpufreq_online: Failed to initialize policy for cpu: 1 (-19)

[    0.641873] cpufreq: cpufreq_online: Failed to initialize policy for cpu: 2 (-19)

[    0.641956] cpufreq: cpufreq_online: Failed to initialize policy for cpu: 3 (-19)

[    0.642048] cpufreq: cpufreq_online: Failed to initialize policy for cpu: 4 (-19)

[    0.642048] cpufreq: cpufreq_online: Failed to initialize policy for cpu: 5 (-19)

[    0.984906] sd 0:0:0:0: [sda] Assuming drive cache: write through
```

What is the failed policies and how should I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using virtual machines or a hypervisor? If yes so, you should update your hypervisor host to the latest version so it can support the kernel version.

CPUFreq stands for CPU frequency scaling which enables the operating system to scale the CPU frequency up or down in order to save power.
I'm not sure why you're getting this error since there may be many possible reasons, but if you're using a hypervisor host - such as ESXi - and your OSes are working fine after the boot and you're only getting this error whilst the boot time, you need to update your Hypervisor host since it does not fully support the newly upgraded kernel version.

If you're getting the same error on the latest version of hypervisors, or if you're not using virtual machines and it's happening on your primary OS, you need to check if your hardware is working fine or not. But this is not CentOS or RHEL problem.

Comment: Yes it was due to the hypervisor host version, thank you so much for the answer, I fixed my problem about 2 weeks ago but forgot to come up with the fix earlier. Thanks.